# How to switch to an encrypted port?

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, port

Currently my reactjs website is on port 8080, and I'm trying to move it onto port 443, but it doesn't allow me to. It says I need admin permissions. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide more information on what actions you're taking for this to occur. Also as an FYI there is not an encrypted port, the port 443 is the default port for serving HTTPS but the application must be configured to serve via TLS :)

Comment: See [privileged ports](https://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html) and [How to setup nginx for react](https://codeburst.io/how-to-setup-nginx-for-react-a504f38f95ed).

Comment: @ChrisWilliams Currently I am setting it up so that yarn run runs "PORT=443 npm run" and it errors out